# Sending Keyboard Shortcuts to OSX instead of separate commands

Tags: macos, keyboard, osx-mavericks, hid

I was wondering how osx interprets keyboard shortcuts vs multiple keys being pressed at the same time.

For example, I have the control + left setup to move spaces to the left.  When I use my keyboard osx interprets it as a shortcut.

Using http://manytricks.com/keycodes/ it does not even register, the OS seems to short-circuit the command on seems to know that it corresponds to a keyboard shortcut.

When using an external usb footswitch that sends the control key signal and the keyboard to send the left key signal the os Does not interpret it as a shortcut but instead interprets this as a control + left key As seen in the photo below

[image]

I posted this on apple.stackexchange but was hoping for a more technical answer
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140732/sending-controlleft-command-with-external-footswitch-delcom-only-picking-up-c

The goal is to get the footswitch to send a correct control signal (key codes says it is sending the exact same control signal as when I hit the left control key on my keyboard)

The footswitch works as expected under ubuntu

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh boy, from kinesis [website](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/savant-elite-3-pedal-3/)

Note: Modifier actions from one USB device cannot modify the input of a second USB device due to limitations designed into the Apple operating system. Example: Shift, Control, Command, or Option keystrokes programmed into the footswitch cannot modify the input of a separate USB keyboard or mouse. However, a key sequence like ‘Cmd-W’ or ‘Cmd-Shift-left arrow’ will work on a Macintosh if the entire sequence of keystrokes has been pre-programmed into the footswitch. (Footswitch can only be programmed on a Windows PC).

I just tried this using my usb keyboard and built in osx keyboard and it seems to be true. I can hit control + left on my usb keyboard and it works fine but control on my usb keyboard + left on the builtin keyboard does not work:(